# Draw a line with a gradient using NSBezierPath, CAShapeLayer, and CAGradientLayer

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift5

I have a macOS app where I draw lines and other figures.

I use NSBezierPath to form the lines or figures and then add it to the CAShapeLayer's path and finally, add the CAShapeLayer to the view.

This all works fine and I have a single stroke color. However, I want the lines/figures ***not*** to be of a single color but of multiple colors(gradient). I know this can be done through CAGradientLayer and tried a few examples from other SO questions showing iOS variants but they didn't work for me.

Below is a code snippet from the app:

```
startPoint = point

currentPath = NSBezierPath()
currentShape = CAShapeLayer()

currentShape?.lineWidth = lineWeight
currentShape?.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
currentShape?.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor

currentShape?.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
currentShape?.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round

currentPath?.move(to: point)
currentPath?.line(to: point)

currentShape?.path = currentPath?.cgPath

view.layer?.addSublayer(currentShape!)

currentGradient = CAGradientLayer()
currentGradient?.mask = currentShape
currentGradient?.frame = currentShape!.frame
currentGradient?.colors = [NSColor.red.cgColor, NSColor.black.cgColor]

view.layer?.addSublayer(currentGradient!)

// some more code here that I omitted (to draw shapes with NSBezierPath)

if let shape = currentShape {
    shape.path = currentPath?.cgPath
    currentGradient?.mask = shape
    currentGradient?.frame = shape.frame
}
```

If I remove the code that involves `currentGradient` then I see the lines/figures (in one solid color) but when I add the gradient part, I do not see anything. What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Any help or hints would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have searched, then you know the answer. You cannot stroke a shape with a gradient. Instead, you *mask* to a gradient; the shape layer becomes the mask whereby the gradient layer is revealed. Example (`v` is a view in the window):

```
    let grad = CAGradientLayer()
    grad.frame = v.bounds
    v.layer?.addSublayer(grad)
    grad.colors = [NSColor.red.cgColor, NSColor.blue.cgColor]
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.frame = v.bounds
    shape.lineWidth = 3
    shape.fillColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
    shape.strokeColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
    let path = CGPath(ellipseIn: v.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4, dy: 4), transform: nil)
    shape.path = path
    grad.mask = shape
```

[image]

Comment: Updated my question with the non-working code I currently have.

Comment: Well one very obvious problem with that code is that all your layers have zero size. You won't see much happen that way!

Comment: I have purposefully omitted some parts of the code where I modify the NSBezierPath (if this is what you are referring to)

Comment: This worked. Can't thank you enough @matt So, basically I changed `currentGradient?.frame = shape.frame` to `currentGradient?.frame = view.bounds`.